# Solving the PDE: $f(D,D')z=a^{\alpha x+\beta y}$ where $D=\partial /\partial x$, $D'=\partial /\partial y$ and $f(D,D')$ is a homogenous function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, exponential-function

I have to solve $f(D,D')z=a^{\alpha x+\beta y}$, I've only solved the case when $a=e$, and by analogy I tried to conjecture a solution to the particular integral, and it was as under, where $n$ is the degree of the homogenous function $f(D,D')$.

$$z=\frac{1}{f(\alpha, \beta)(\log(a))^{n}}a^{\alpha x+\beta y}$$

Could anyone confirm whether this is correct. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @JJacquelin It is any polynomial function of $D$ and $D'$, for example, $D^{2}+2DD'+D'^{2}$, where $D=\partial /\partial x$ and $D'=\partial /\partial y$.

Comment: The writing of the question is still ambiguous. If the PDE is $$\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}A_k\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^k\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^{n-k}=a^{\alpha x+\beta y}$$ your answer $$z=\frac{1}{f(\alpha, \beta)(\log(a))^{n}}a^{\alpha x+\beta y}$$is not correct in general $(n>1)$. Put your  proposed solution into the PDE and check if it agrees.